# Text alignment in Definition Lists

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align my text using definition lists.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/x2bgfbwv/2/

I need the pink boxes to start once the red boxes stop.

**html:**

```
<dl>
    <dt>Address</dt>
    <dd>Test <br />
Another Test <br />
A Final Test</dd>

    <dt>Phone</dt>
    <dd>Test</dd>

    <dt>Fax</dt>
    <dd>Test</dd>

    <dt>Email</dt>
    <dd><a href="mailto:">email@testtesttesttest.org</a></dd>
</dl>
```

**css:**

```
dl {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    border-spacing: 0;
    background:green;
}
dd {
    display: inline-block;
    background:pink;
}
dd:after {
        display: block;
        content: '';
      }


dt {
    padding-left: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    background:red;
    min-width:110px;
    width:110px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    dl {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    border-spacing: 0;
    background:green;
}
dd {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    background:pink;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
}

dt {
    gin: 0 0 5px;
    padding-left: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    background:red;
    min-width:110px;
    float: left;
}
```

add these codes

[JS Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/sabipu/x2bgfbwv/5/)

Answer (score 2):

Add this code:

```
   dt {
      display: inline-block;
    }

    dd {
      margin-left: -4px;
  }
```

Also you can remove, the :after pseudo-element.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/x2bgfbwv/3/
Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. I need the pink boxes to be aligned with the red boxes. Horizontally.